# How to use the exported variables of another commonjs module without declare them again?

Tags: module, declaration, commonjs

Suppose I have a module `models.js`:

```
exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
exports.Question = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
exports.Answer = mongoose.model('Answer', AnswerSchema);
exports.Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

Now I want to use it in another file:

```
var models = require('./models');
var User = models.User;
var Question = models.Question;
var Answer = models.Answer;
var Comment = models.Comment

// then use them
var user = new User();
```

It is boring that I have to declare all the models I defined in `models.js`.

Is there any way to simplify it, that I don't need to declare the models again:

```
var models = require('./models');

// !!! do some magic

var user = new User();
```

Answer (score 0):

Curious why don't you want to simply do with no magic needed - what is issue with simple ..

```
var models = require('./models');
var user = new models.User();
```